# c# Get color from webcam. Wrong color all the time?

Tags: c#, colors

I am using cor_xy to get the colors from the originalmaster(webcam) and color_xy_processada to display the color on the picturebox.

I am using x,y from the image (e.X and e.Y) but it gives me the wrong color.

Maybe it's because the image is inverted 180 degrees Y axis and stretched? I dont know, maybe it's the code.

[image: Image from the Application (clicked on green and got red)]

```
          cor_xy = new Bitmap(originalmaster.Image);//cria imagem para mostrar a cor na posicao x,y
            int posX = e.X; //coordenadas x
            int posY = e.Y; //coordenadas y
                            //mostra nas labels
            lblratox.Text = posX.ToString();
            lblratoy.Text = posY.ToString();
            Color Get_Color = cor_xy.GetPixel(posX, posY);//verifica a cor em x,y
            int a = Get_Color.A;
            int r = Get_Color.R;
            int g = Get_Color.G;
            int b = Get_Color.B;
            Color _color = Color.FromArgb(a, r, g, b);

            //Mostra nas labels
            lblr.Text = r.ToString();
            lblg.Text = g.ToString();
            lblb.Text = b.ToString();
            lbla.Text = a.ToString();
            cor_xy_processada = new Bitmap(selecao_cor.Image);
            for (int i = 0; i < cor_xy_processada.Width; i++) //percorre a imagem 

            {
                for (int j = 0; j < cor_xy_processada.Height; j++)
                {
                    cor_xy_processada.SetPixel(i, j, _color);

                }
            }

            selecao_cor.Image = cor_xy_processada;
```

The image is flipped and stretched. It's 640x360 image and the picturebox is 320x180:

originalmaster.Image.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipY)
originalmaster.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;

I dont know the webcam image resolution. maybe there is a better way to display the image keeping it downscaled 1:1?

**Edit:It works if I use auto-size**

> `originalmaster.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.AutoSize.`

**Or works if**
`currentFrame = grabber.QueryFrame().Resize(320, 240,Emgu.CV.CvEnum.INTER.CV_INTER_CUBIC);`

***but the image is VERY BLURRY now...***

**But the problem still remains. I cant use AutoSize because it covers almost all application size.
Any ideas how to downscale the webcam image to the Bitmap of the picturebox?**

Comment: I don't see an error in this part of your code. Can you provide some more info? Is the image scaled? How is it scaled? What color are you getting and what did you expect? What colors are you getting on the pixel (0, 0) (0, width) (0, height) and (width, height)? Whats the green ring and what is the white arrow supposed to show?

Comment: The arrow shows where i clicked. And the ring just forget it, it's nothing

Comment: There might be a conversion problem as well, but it's impossible to tell without know what data you are getting versus what youre expecting on the respective pixel.

Comment: look my edit please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `e` is your mouse eventargs, try:

```
   double ratioX = (double)or_xy_processada.Width / (double)ourPicturebox.Width
   double ratioY = (double)or_xy_processada.Height / (double)ourPicturebox.Height;
   int posX = (int) (e.X * ratioX);
   int posY = (int) (e.Y * ratioY);
```

Comment: I tried this but now it says i dont have any image because i have try/catch code.

Comment: cannot convert double to int.

Comment: i tried with int on ratiox and ratio y but still failing. it goes to the catch code.

Comment: now gives me always the point 0,0. posX = 0 and posY = 0 and it makes sence.

Comment: now gives me always the point 0,0. posX = 0 and posY = 0 and it makes sence. it's like posX= e.X / 640*640 which is very near 0.

Comment: e is a coordinate relative to your PictureBox. You need to scale it up to the original size of you image to hit the right position. So one of the values in the equation I provided is 0. You check which it is and why.

Comment: The calculation is for example: posX = 123 * (640 / 300); where 123 is the position you clicked, 300 the width of you picturebox and 640 the width of your image.

Comment: man when i do this double ratioX = (double)or_xy_processada.Width / (double)ourPicturebox.Width the result is 0

Comment: double ratioX = cor_xy_processada.Width / originalmaster.Width; it's 66/320 = basically 0.

Comment: maybe I can give you the code? it's easier for you i think

Comment: radioX needs to be "Original size of your image" divided by "Size of your PictureBox". Sorry, I don't know how to make this any clearer.